# Join 2 tables and only keep the records that exists in tableB and not in tableA

Tags: sql, join, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables, tableA and tableB.
I want to do a join and only keep the values that exist in tableB but don't exist in table A.
Can anyone help me?

```
TableA:                                      TableB:

|ID    |Name    |                            |ID    |Name     |
-----------------                            ------------------
|1     |BOB     |                            |1     |BOB      |
|2     |JOS     |                            |2     |JOS      |
                                             |3     |JEF      |


OUTPUT RESULT:
|ID    |Name    |                        
-----------------             
|3     |JEF     |
```

Comment: Did you try WHERE ... NOT IN ...?

Comment: No, I tried by a join but I can't find a good way